# In Ruby on rails, how can I figure out which class mix in which module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I want to find out some way to get what methods are available in certain class?

Should I check out the online document or use the ri tool, I would be great that if there's a graphic tool to show the relation between each class and module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to see the methods available for any class, try this:

```
CLASS_NAME.methods                     # list of all methods available
CLASS_NAME.instance_methods            # list of all instance methods
CLASS_NAME.public_instance_methods     # list of all instance methods which are public
CLASS_NAME.private_instance_methods    # list of all instance methods which are private
CLASS_NAME.protected_instance_methods  # list of all instance methods which are protected
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DRX](http://drx.rubyforge.org/)